# SQL Complex query with inner join and where between

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, where-clause

I can't get my head around why my query won't work and I've searched through existing topics already.
**My goal**
I'm trying to display the top 5 complaint types in a selected period from my MySQL.

**Expected result**
A table of 5 rows, showing the COUNT in the first column, and the description of my Ticket Type in the second column

### **Query I'm using which returns an error**

```html
SELECT
  COUNT(t.ticketType) AS total_amount, 
  tt.typeTekst AS description
  FROM Ticket t
  WHERE t.ticketStartTime BETWEEN 1612443540 AND 1613393340
  INNER JOIN TicketType tt ON t.ticketType = tt.typeId
  GROUP BY description
  ORDER BY total_amount desc
  LIMIT 5
```

### **Similar queries that do work- but don't meet my expectations**

**Table without the proper ticket description**

```
SELECT
  COUNT(t.ticketType) AS total_amount, 
  t.ticketType AS description
  FROM Ticket t
  WHERE t.ticketStartTime BETWEEN 1612443540 AND 1613393340
  GROUP BY description
  ORDER BY total_amount desc
  LIMIT 5
```

| total_amount | description |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 30 |

**Table without the selected period, but with description**

```html
SELECT
  COUNT(t.ticketType) AS total_amount,
  tt.typeDescription AS description
  FROM Ticket t
  INNER JOIN TicketType AS tt ON t.ticketType = tt.typeId 
  GROUP BY description
  ORDER BY total_amount desc
  LIMIT 5
```

| total_amount | description |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | TicketType Placeholder A |
| 10 | TicketType Placeholder B |
| 8 | TicketType Placeholder C |
| 5 | TicketType Placeholder D |
| 4 | TicketType Placeholder E |

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `WHERE` is a SQL *clause* that follows the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where clause after Joining all the tables. Please try below query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(t.ticketType) AS total_amount, 
  tt.typeTekst AS description
  FROM Ticket t
  INNER JOIN TicketType tt ON t.ticketType = tt.typeId
  WHERE t.ticketStartTime BETWEEN 1612443540 AND 1613393340
  GROUP BY description
  ORDER BY total_amount desc
  LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Ohh you're a livesaver! Wasted soo much time trying to figure out what was wrong, and it's such a little detail..
Thank you!